# How can I store and load a big variable in python?

Tags: python, list, pickle

My question is related with the storage and the loading of a big variable in python. Specifically, among other variables (v1, v2), I want to store a list of nested lists (v3)(bool type).

```
v3 = [[[False] for x in range(6000)] for x in range(6000)]
```

Then, I perform some operation so I change some of the `False` values into `True`.

I have tried to used `pickle` for saving with the argument `protocol=4` since the total memory of my variables (v1, v2, v3) exceeds the 4GiB:

```
filename = 'path.pkl'
with open(filename,'wb') as f:
      pickle.dump([v1, v2, v3],f, protocol=4)
```

I have used the `pickle.load` command to import my data.

```
    with open('path.pkl','rb') as f:
        (v1,v2,v3) = pickle.load(f)
```

but I got an error: `AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'FrozenNDArray' on <module 'pandas.core.indexes.frozen' from 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\core\\indexes\\frozen.py'>`

Then, I tried the `pd.read_pickle` and I was able to load my data.

The problem with `pickle` is that my variable `v3` is no longer a boolean one. The variable stores the number of indexes whose value is `True`. I have confirmed that since I printed the a specific list before and after the saving. Before the saving the list was a `boolean` one, and after it stores indexes.

Do you have a suggestion/alternative for a more efficient method so I can efficiently store and load my big variables?

Comment: Can you use numpy? You can create a numpy array with your data and then save it with numpy.save. Load with numpy.load

Comment: What's the operation that you perform?

Comment: @jkr. Sounds good. However, I would like to store all of my variables and load them together.

Comment: Is there a reason the innermost item is a list of a single boolean, rather than simply a boolean?  (i.e. remove the brackets `[]` from around `False`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with arrays, then I would suggest using numpy. One can use `numpy.savez()` to save multiple arrays into the same file.

```py
import numpy as np

# Create the data.
v2 = np.full((6000, 6000, 1), fill_value=True)
v3 = np.full((6000, 6000, 1), fill_value=False)

# Save the data.
np.savez("data.npz", v2=v2, v3=v3)

# Load the data.
with np.load("data.npz") as f:
    v2_loaded = f["v2"]
    v3_loaded = f["v3"]
```